# xamarin ios10 no message in logging

Tags: iphone, logging, xamarin, device, ios10

When I view the device log in Visual Studio when trying to debug my app which runs in the background (so no normal debugging is available) I get empty messages.

I am using Debug.WriteLine with the defaul System.Diagnostics, no custom stuff whatsoever. Tried restarting everything, but that didn't help. It does hit the lines because the code is executed and I see the empty message lines so it is partially working but the most important info is not visible.

It works fine on an iPhone 4S (iOS 9) but since today I'm using an iPhone SE (iOS 10) and the message is empty.

Doesn't make life easier not being able to debug and not being able to view the debug text :(

Any idea anyone?

Cheers,

Rob

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmVz7.jpg)

Comment: Try using `Console.Writeline` instead to see if the messages show up...

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, but didn't make any difference

Comment: Can you create an MVCE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'll try to create one.

Comment: @jgoldberger: I just created a new Blank Xaml App, removed all projects except the iOS app.
Added Debug.WriteLine("This is a test log line"); in the FinishedLaunching of the AppDelegate, just before the LoadApplication line.

When I run it on iOS9 (iPhone 4S) it works fine. On iOS 10.2.1 (iPhone SE) I get nothing. This time not even an empty line.

If you want the project for repro, let me know where to send it.

Comment: I just noticed the logging in XCode doesn't show the lines either. So Visual Studio Device Log does show the same as XCode. Looks like something is going wrong with writing to the log.

Comment: So that would seem to be an Apple bug.

Comment: @jgoldberger Either that or the writing to the log isn't done correctly. I can't confirm that the logging is or isn't working correctly using an XCode project. So you're not off the hook yet ;)

Considering the fact that the logging does show Xamarin logging (from the framework) it would seem to me that it's more likely to be an issue with writing to the log.

Comment: OK, I confirmed logging using NSLog is working from xcode as expected, so this does seem to be a bug in Xam.iOS. I will investigate further and file a bug report and post an answer when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes, this does appear to be a bug in Xamarin.iOS. Bug filed:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52308

This is a regression in the latest Stable and Alpha/Beta releases (works as expected in the last stable release, Xam.iOS 10.2.1.5)

Xamarin engineers will now discuss this issue on the bug report. If you would like to receive a notification when the bug is updated, you can add yourself to the CC list for the bug.  Please note that you will need to create an account on that system if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!